# Bootstrap Toggle Menu Fails to load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm sure this issue is the result of conflicting code, but I cant seem to find it. I've removed all of the page except for the menu bar area. I'd would appreciate any help in getting the drop down to appear. It may be better to just recreate the top portion of the page at this point, but I thought I would check here first in case its just an oversight. 
Thanks in advance.

```
<https://jsfiddle.net/cxLap188/#&togetherjs=GqBl9GC4UQ>
```

Comment: how do you expect us to help you when we have NO CODE???

Comment: I attached a link:https://jsfiddle.net/cxLap188/#&togetherjs=GqBl9GC4UQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that jsfiddle you have 2 `div` with `id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"`, so the `navbar-toggle` works with the first it finds, just delete the one you dont need (the one after that `<h3 class="hedLogo">` I guess).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response that was fast.